# javax.naming.namingexception error accessing to repository: can not connect to orb

Tags: java, jboss, migration, jndi, jboss-eap-7

I am getting below error while deploying application in Jboss eap 7.1
I am able to successfully generating application ear file.
Also updated all Jboss related configurations.
Database connecting successfully in localhost.
Error-

```
java.lang.runtimeexception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datasource' defined in SevletContext Resource: Invocation of init method failed
Nested exception is javax.naming.namingexception error accessing to repository: can not connect to orb
```

**standalone-full.xml**

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/myDS" pool-name="myDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:testDB</connection-url>
                    <driver>oracleDS</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>user</user-name>
                        <password>password</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>.
```

**Application-Context.xml**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/myDS"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: How exactly are you doing the DB lookup?Could you share the code?Is test connection successful for DB on eap 7.1?

Comment: Yes Sweta Test connection successful for DB in jboss portal.
I cant share the exact code here due to certain limitations.
I will update with some dummy code

Comment: This looks like bean creation isn't successful